Follow-Up on Assistant Professorship Offer Status
I have completed several rounds of interviews for an assistant professorship position with a university. In June, the department chair verbally informed me that they wanted to hire me. At their request, I presented my preferences for the start-up package (e.g., lab space, start-up funding, number of postdocs and PhD students) and my proposed start date, which they were okay with. Following this, I presented my research funding plans. Subsequently, I received an email stating that my case had been forwarded to the dean for approval. I was also verbally assured that the dean had been involved throughout my interview process and related discussions.
Given the positive feedback from the department chair, I expected to receive an official offer letter within a couple of weeks. However, it has now been nearly four weeks since I was notified that the dean’s approval is pending, and I am starting to feel anxious about the delay, especially since the verbally agreed start date is approaching very soon. I am contemplating whether I should reach out to the department chair or search committee for a progress update, or if I should continue to wait. Do you think it's okay for me to send a follow-up email? Also, is it normal for the dean's approval process to delay the official offer letter this long?

"...the verbally agreed start date is approaching..." - You can frame your request for an update around this. It's entirely reasonable to point out that if they want you to start on the agreed date, they need to confirm the position as a matter of urgency so that you have time to make your personal arrangements (e.g. resign from current job, find accommodation, book travel, etc.)

Related: How long does it usually take to hear back for academic positions? Why haven't I heard back and when should I follow up?. I realize your situation is a little different, but the answer is ultimately the same; no one on the internet can tell you what's going on.

@avid You completely understand my situation. I was feeling a sense of urgency because I need to figure out my lease, flight, movers, etc. Additionally, I wanted to start advertising for undergraduate and MS student positions for the fall semester, as well as recruiting PhD students and postdocs.

Yes, you can send that letter asking for current status and offering to provide any additional information they might need. If you've met the chair that might be the one to send it to, otherwise the head of the search committee.
Vacations at this time might explain the longer than seems usual delay. And, there might be a lot of signatures needed.

Please have some sympathy for overworked underappreciated faculty overburdened with departmental service and don't send it to the head of the search committee. Their job is done and they have plenty of other things to do. Once they handed the recommendation for hire over to the Chair, it is out of their hands. This is obviously now in the hands of administration. You can follow up with the Chair as they are directly involved with the Dean for hires.

@Buffy Thank you for your response. I was hesitant because I didn’t want to pressure anyone or leave a negative impression, especially since I believed everything was now beyond the professors' control. Without an official offer letter, it's hard to relax and focus only on positive things. I will try reaching out to them.
